# CSS Grids nested and auto-fill height issue

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm having an issue with nested CSS Grids where the nested grid using a repeating auto-fill template-column that then forces the height of the outer grid.

I've created an example here: https://codepen.io/davshoward/pen/XzKKOG

You can see how the height of the content area is far too high. If you remove the line:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 17.5rem);
```

... it highlights why it's the height it is.

Anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: The question is not entirely clear. Is this what you're after? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QOEGyL

Comment: Apologies. With that layout, there's a huge amount of white space below the blue boxes that is caused by the grid-template-columns and I don't know why. if you remove that line, you can see that it has one box per row which fills the white space beneath. The height on the .main element is incorrectly calculated.

Comment: When the nested grid comes into play with its `grid-template-columns` rule it *reduces the height of the grid item in the second column due to wrapping*. Now, both columns in the main container remain the same height, but the content of the second column is essentially half the height, leaving a gap underneath. If you apply borders or background-colors to the elements you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Is it possible to address? It seems counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: It's not counter-intuitive. Your primary container has one row (by default). The height of that row is set by the tallest column (the `aside`). You're then wrapping the content of the second column, which makes ***the content*** shorter. But that has nothing to do with the row height of the primary container.

Comment: If you change the "auto-fill" to a number (e.g. 3) to force a certain number of columns it doesn't have the huge space below - it only occurs when using "auto-fill".

Why would it occur for one setting but not another?

Comment: One way to solve the problem is to remove the extra container. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qVNJXp?editors=1100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue.

The offending parameter was the "auto" on the outer grid.

Changing it from "15rem auto" to "15rem 1fr" allowed the nesting to act as I was hoping.